# Is it possible to print out the assembly code in ollydbg

Tags: assembly, ollydbg

I wanted to know if it is possible to print out the assembly code which I analyze in ollydbg. I mean to have all of that on a paper. Sometimes I do not have access to my laptop. In such cases I would take the paper version and analyze it. Is that possible ? Is there a plugin or something like that available ?

best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if copying the display from cpu window is what you want to achieve
**ollydbg 1.10**

if you want the dis assembly of main module say notepad.exe make the module visible in cpu pane (`alt+m follow or alt+ e -> view code in cpu`)

```
in the cpu pane right click -> copy > select all -> right click -> to file
```

**odbg 201**

```
rightclick -> select module -> right click -> edit select all -> right click -> copy as table
```

open say notepad and paste it and save it as my disassembled_exe .txt

```
>head -n 6 "copyofcpu.txt" | awk "{ print  $1,$2}"
01001000 <&ADVAPI32.RegQueryValueExW>
01001004 <&ADVAPI32.RegCloseKey>
01001008 <&ADVAPI32.RegCreateKeyW>
0100100C <&ADVAPI32.IsTextUnicode>
01001010 <&ADVAPI32.RegQueryValueExA>
01001014 <&ADVAPI32.RegOpenKeyExA>

>head -n 6 "New Text Document.txt" | awk"{print $1,$2}"
CPU Disasm
Address Hex
01001000 &ADVAPI32.RegOpenKeyExA
01001004 &ADVAPI32.RegQueryValueExA
01001008 &ADVAPI32.RegCloseKey
0100100C ⌂ADVAPI32_NULL_THUNK_DATA
```

Comment: oh, thanks...xD That was exactly what I need.